# What must I do to plot the graph of $\sin x=\sin y$

Tags: calculus

I must represent the domain of the function: $$z=\frac{x-y}{\sin x-\sin y}$$ 
Therefore, $\sin x\neq\sin y$. 
So I must plot $\sin x=\sin y$. How do I do this?

Comment: Do you perhaps mean sin instead of sen?

Comment: Sen(x) is the portuguese, and italian spelling of it. http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seno, http://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seno_(matematica). Probably the same in some other languages too.

Comment: Just draw  the graph of $\sin x$ and then draw a horizontal line crossing it. The intersection points are the $x$ values that share the same sine value. You do not what your $x$ and $y$ be any two of these intersection points. How would you summarize this situation?

Comment: For any given $x$, $\sin x = \sin((2n + 1)\pi - x) = \sin(x + 2n\pi)$ for $n \in \mathbb Z$, and this exhausts all possibilities. So, $\sin x = \sin y$ when $y = x + 2n\pi$ or $y = (2n + 1)\pi -x$. The graph is the union of these infinitely many straight lines.

Comment: Graphically, it's a grid rotated by 45 degrees.

Comment: I'd suggest dividing the plane into squares with edge $\pi$ (the first one centered about the origin, and then just tile around). In each of those, plotting the graph is straightforward.

Answer (score 1):

$\sin y = \sin x \iff y = n\pi +(-1)^nx,\text{ for some $n\in \mathbb{Z}$}$.

Putting $n=0$, we see that $y = x$ is on the graph.

Putting $n=1$, we see that $y = -x +\pi$ is also on the graph.

So for all even $n$, we have the set of straight lines:

$y = x + -4\pi,\,\quad y = x + -2\pi,\,\quad y = x,\,\quad y = x + 2\pi$ and so on so forth.

Likewise, for all odd $n$:

$y = -x + -3\pi,\,\quad y = -x + -\pi,\,\quad y = -x + \pi,\,\quad y = -x + 3\pi$ and so forth.

Comment: Did you mean to say these are to be excluded from $xy$ planeto get the domain, as opposed to "it is on graph"?

Comment: @Maesumi Yes, you are right that these have to be excluded from the domain. I believe the OP is trying to plot all the points that are not in the domain of his/her function. These points as he/she concludes, precisely satisfy $\sin x = \sin y$.

Answer (score 1):

$\sin y = \sin x \iff y = x +2k\pi \text{ or } y = \pi-x+2k\pi,\text{ for some $k\in \mathbb{Z}$}$.

The two equations on the RHS of the equivalence correspond to lines.

Therefore, the set $\{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 \mid \sin x = \sin y\}$ (over which the function is *not* defined) is a "crisscross" of such lines; the restriction of that set over $[-40,40]^2$ looks as follows:

[image]

---

$\LaTeX$ code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
 \def\PI{3.1416}
 \begin{axis}[xlabel=$x$, ylabel=$y$,ymin=-40,ymax=40]
  \foreach \k in {-15,...,15}{
   \addplot[red, ultra thin,domain=-40:40] (x,x+2*\PI*\k);
   \addplot[red, ultra thin,domain=-40:40] (x,\PI-x+2*\PI*\k);
  }
 \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

$$\begin{align}
\sin(y) &=\sin(x)\\
\implies y&=\arcsin(\sin(x))+2\pi\,n\text{ or }\pi-\arcsin(\sin(x))+2\pi\,n\\
\implies y&=\arcsin(\sin(x))+2\pi\,n\text{ or }\pi-\arcsin(\sin(x))+2\pi\,n\\
\end{align}$$
for some $n\in\mathbb{Z}$.

Now $\arcsin(\sin(x))$ is a sawtooth function with slope $1$ over $(-\pi/2,\pi/2)$ and slope $-1$ over $(\pi/2,3\pi/2)$. Accounting for all vertical translations by an integer multiple of $2\pi$, and then also for all vertical reflections over the $x$-axis followed by a vertical translation by $\pi$, the domain is the complement of a criss-cross lattice with a generating square with vertices $(-\pi/2,-\pi/2),(-3\pi/2,\pi/2),(-\pi/2,3\pi/2),(\pi/2,\pi/2)$.